# Подзапрос к другому серверу

Tags: php

Как это реализовать средствами PHP?

Задача.

> Есть Клиент, Сервер1, Сервер2.
> Клиент по POST посылает запрос с данными к Серверу1.
> Сервер1 обрабатывает данные и посылает подзапрос к Серверу2 (и при этом ещё не отвечает Серверу1).
> Получив ответ от Сервера2, Сервер1 формирует ответ и посылает его Клиенту.

Желательно пример кода.

Answer (score 1):

Просто на одном и другом серверах пхп скрипты обрабатывающие данные входные и дающие ответ. На первом просто напросто будет еще в теле документа фунция запроса с передачей данных на второй. Честно говоря, не вижу никаких трудностей вообще тут. Разве что вы не знаете, как из пхп делать POST запрос.